# do webservers impose character limits on get requests

Tags: http, http-get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

I have an ajax request using GET method.

on one server (apache) the GET request can handle >512 characters, but on another server 512 is the limit.

I am using the same browser.

... by the way if I do the ajax request using post instead, no problems.

---

**EDIT**

[www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15) ... *10.4.15 414 Request-URI Too Long*

*The server is refusing to service the request because the Request-URI is longer than the server is willing to interpret. This rare condition is only likely to occur when a client has improperly converted a POST request to a GET request with long query information, when the client has descended into a URI "black hole" of redirection (e.g., a redirected URI prefix that points to a suffix of itself), or when the server is under attack by a client attempting to exploit security holes present in some servers using fixed-length buffers for reading or manipulating the Request-URI.*

Comment: charles, that is asking if the server should return an error or not if a failed get is delivered to the server... which is different ... I am asking if the server, itself, imposes a limit.

Comment: Please refer to the duplicate for the relevant RFC-compliant limits and current behavior as seen in the wild.  If you see limits other than those contained in the RFCs and known browser limits, chances are that it's a problem with your code, not the client or server.

Comment: charles, thanks ... but the rfc reference doesn't mention the server attribute that places a limit ... it merely alludes to the limitation ... which I guess answers my question, literally speaking .... obviously I would like to know more about it than merely 'yes' or 'no' answer, which is all the _10.4.15 414 Request-URI Too Long_ gives me.